# Rust build error: failed to run custom build command for `glib-sys v0.8.0`

Tags: windows, rust-cargo, glib

I am trying to build a Rust program on Windows 10. When trying to compile a Rust file with I keep getting the following error messages.

```
cargo run
   Compiling glib-sys v0.8.0
   Compiling const_fn v0.4.9
   Compiling quote v1.0.21
   Compiling socket2 v0.4.4
   Compiling net2 v0.2.37
   Compiling winreg v0.7.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `glib-sys v0.8.0`
```

They are caused by:

```
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\artem\zabotay\backend\target\debug\build\glib-sys-b1ba74e042d8283d\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "glib-2.0" "glib-2.0 >= 2.42"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1
  error: could not find system library 'glib-2.0' required by the 'glib-sys' crate
```

I look through other questions, but found no answer about glib2.0 fix

--- stderr
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'glib-2.0' found Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found

```
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

How to fix this error?